# how to send google cloud messaging in queing?

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

Hi i am sending notifications to android mobile from php server. Its working fine with single notifications. But if i send 2 notifications at once. First notification is replacing by second notifications. is there any way i can see 2 notifications in queing (i.e like sms inbox message format).

Below is my php code:

```
<?php
define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "API id");
define("GOOGLE_GCM_URL", "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");

function send_gcm_notify($reg_id, $message) {

$fields = array(
    'registration_ids'  => array( $reg_id ),
    'data'              => array( "message" => $message ),
);

$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, GOOGLE_GCM_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('Problem occurred: ' . curl_error($ch));
}

curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
}

$reg_id = "device id";
$msg = "Google Cloud Messaging working well";
 for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++){
 send_gcm_notify($reg_id, $msg);}
```

Comment: Yes you can do that , by appending some id with text , you can say group id, Store all the messages in local database and while displaying you can show it like chat

Answer (score 0):

since you are sending data to the same notification builder.. second one is placed on top of first one. that is the default way of notification. but if you want to send multiple notifications for two tasks, you should use two notification builders and filter the received messages and call relevant notification builder. but there are limitations, so this depends on your program requirement.

Comment: is it android side or server side i need to do .

Comment: First notification is replacing by second one ..instead of that i need to show second one on top of first one....to achieve the did i need to work on android side or php side

Comment: in android side and php side both... but it is not possible if you need to show 100notifications in such occasions you should use Notification stack as in gmail app... I have given the link as another answer check it

Comment: you need to send additional field with your server data to know which notification is execute.. and in android side you need to get the json data in onMessaveReceived() method and execute first or second notification builder by using if-else

Comment: actually i am php programmer android side is taking care by android people.can u tell me what i need to change in server side...and give me sample code tutorial for android so that i can giv it to them.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for notification as following image

[StackYour notifications](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html)

[image: Notification Stack Image]